# Java - GridBagLayout/Insets position JLabel under another

Tags: java, swing, awt, gridbaglayout, insets

I use a `GridBagLayout` and have two `JLabels`. I want the first one to appear on the top left and the next one right below it and to the right. I use:

```
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

    JLabel jl = new JLabel("This is a JLabel!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    gbc.ipadx = 87;
    gbc.ipady = 220;
    add(jl, gbc);
```

And is displayed fine as first pic shows. Then I try to create and add the second one but I have some troubles positioning below and right the first one. Maybe I do something wrong with the `Insets` as it gives extra space from the top:

```
    gbc.insets = new Insets(500, 10, 10, 10);
    JLabel jl2 = new JLabel("This is a JLabel!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jl2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    gbc.ipadx = 87;
    gbc.ipady = 220;
    add(jl2, gbc);
```

How can I fix this? Thanks

[image] [image]

Comment: Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) when you ask a question. `I want the first one to appear on the top left and the next one right below it and to the right.` I would guess one component is added to grid (0, 0) and the other to grid (1,1). Start by reading the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for working examples and explanations of how the constraints work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    GridBagLayout gbl=new GridBagLayout();
    setLayout(gbl);
    GridBagConstraints gbc=new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

    JLabel jl = new JLabel("This is a JLabel!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.ipadx = 50;
    gbc.ipady = 50;
    add(jl, gbc);

    gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    JLabel jl2 = new JLabel("This is a JLabel!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jl2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.ipadx = 50;
    gbc.ipady = 50;
    add(jl2, gbc);
```

Use the gridy and gridx attributes to specify the position of the JLabels in the GridBagLayout-Table.